# Google Drive API File list: It is not possible to get the file of shared folder

Tags: google-drive-api

There is a folder shared with everyone (shared set of "Anyone with the link can view").
I want to get all spreadsheets in the folder by using the Drive API.

I tried to get them by using the Files list of Drive API.
Then q parameter is the following.;

- https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='{publishFolderId}' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed = false

But I could not get them. many tmes.

```
// response
{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx\"",
  "selfLink": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "items": [
  ]
}
```

Could I realize the above requirements by using the API of the Files list?

Remarks
In my guess...
Once I open the folder from the web browser, I can get them from the folder.

Althogh I could not get them many times in eary August 2015,  the phenomnon seems to be reolved at this moment.

Comment: are the files in the folder set to public?

Comment: Yes, the files are in the folder shared set of "Anyone with the link can view".